# BASH/DASH: What is the best way to pass array to function?

Tags: bash, shell-script, dash

I have this array:

```
PARAMETERS_OF_COMPONENTS[1]="component1"
PARAMETERS_OF_COMPONENTS[2]="component21 component22 component23"
PARAMETERS_OF_COMPONENTS[3]="component3"
PARAMETERS_OF_COMPONENTS[4]="component41 component42 component43"
```

I want to pass that array to this function:

```
foo()
{
    local param1="$1"
    local param2="$2"
    local array_param="$3"
    . . .

    echo "${PARAMETERS_OF_COMPONENTS[@]}"
}
```

When I pass an array in this manner:

```
foo "$param1" "$param2" "${PARAMETER_OF_COMPONENTS[@]}"
```

then function just prints:

```
component1
```

Also, I've been tried couple of other methods to pass array, but I still didn't find right solution.

How can I pass correctly array to function? Also, solution must be compatible with Dash (at least without bashisms).

**UPD**
@Kusalananda explained to me that Dash doesn't support an arrays. Thank's for clarify.

I will ask another one. How can I pass many parameters to function without pass it directly in manner `$1`,`$2` ... and don't involve global variables? I have several ideas, but I would to listen yours approaches?

My task is to move function from one file to another, but that function uses global variables. I don't want to use global variables. So how to do this in the most right way?

Comment: dash does not support arrays.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank's for clarify! I rephrase my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `sh` shell that does not support arrays and the `local` keyword, you may still use `$@` as an array in the function.  You may pick off the two first arguments with `shift 2` and then use `$@` which now hold all the rest of the arguments.

```
foo () {
    arg1=$1
    arg2=$2

    shift 2  # shift $3 into $1, $4 into $2 etc.

    for n in "$@"; do    # or just: for n do
        printf 'Other argument: %s\n' "$n"
        # other code acting on "$n"
    done
}

foo "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4"
```

Enclose the body of the function in `( ... )` instead of `{ ... }` to make all variables local, if the function does not need to modify global variables and you don't want to pollute the variable namespace with unnecessary variables.

---

Using your original data with `foo` declared as above:

```
set -- "component1" \
       "component21 component22 component23" \
       "component3" \
       "component41 component42 component43"

foo "$param1" "$param2" "$@"
```

---

In a shell that supports arrays and `local`, you would do the exact same thing (but the function may want to use variables declared as `local`), and the call might be

```
foo "arg1" "arg2" "${myarray[@]}"
```

To pass multiple arrays in `bash`, I would use a name reference in the function (requires `bash` release 4.3 or later):

```
foo () {
   local arg1=$1
   local arg2=$2
   local -n arr1=$3
   local -n arr2=$4

   for n in "${arr2[@]}"; do ...; done
}

foo "arg1" "arg2" myarray1 myarray2
```

Note that you can't pass an array variable to the function that has the same name as the corresponding name reference variable in the function (I consider this a bug, it works in `ksh93`).

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I see that `foo "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4"` is the most right way for compatibility between bash and dash. I think in this manner too, but I hoped exists more beautiful (from view point) solution. Please, tell me what `-n` flag mean for the local operator? I didn't find it in man page. (bash 3.2.57).

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I should have said, name references declared with either `declare -n` or `local -n` needs a more recent version of `bash` :-/  I think they were introduced in `bash` release 4.3.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk You could possibly use indirection instead: `${!arr2[@]}`, but I haven't tried this with arrays.

Comment: I've already tried indirection. It works for my version of bash.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk Good! A name reference is more or less the same thing but without the need for the extra syntactical sugar (the `!`).

Comment: I will mark as solved. Thank's for you time! But I'm still watching about beautiful (from view point) solution. If I will want it, I post it.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk See update (in the middle of the answer).

Comment: It's really helpful for me. Thank's again!